# How to solve build failure error?C:\Maven_Project\testjava>mvn clean package->java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: maven, package, illegalstateexception, applicationcontext

```
C:\Maven_Project\testjava>mvn clean package


INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@482cd91f: startup date [Sat Mar 23 20:30:20 IST 2024]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 23, 2024 8:30:20 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@516be40f] to prepare test instance [training.taylor.timetracker.core.TrackerCoreConfigTest@b9b00e0]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:316)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:240)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: training.taylor.timetracker.core.TrackerCoreConfig
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:416)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:128)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
38 more

[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   TrackerCoreConfigTest.testMe » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext
[ERROR]   TrackerTest.testAdd » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext
[ERROR]   TrackerTest.testMe » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Time Tracker (Parent) 0.5.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]`your text`
[INFO] Time Tracker (Parent) .............................. SUCCESS [  0.250 s]
[INFO] Time Tracker (Core) ................................ FAILURE [  5.579 s]
[INFO] Time Tracker (Web) ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.938 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-23T20:30:20+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.2.2:test (default-test) on project time-tracker-core:
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Maven_Project\testjava\core\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :time-tracker-core
```

I tried to build project using mvn clean package and got build failure message and got errors. Please guide to solve error and what's wrong here i did.`

Comment: Please give more context: Which Spring/Spring Boot version do you use? The test is obviously failed? Show the test? Please show the pom file and give more information like JDK, Maven version etc.